# PHP/Javascript chunked upload: IE9 corrupt file if filesize is over upload_max_filesize or post_max_size

Tags: javascript, php, plupload, chunked-encoding

I'm using [Plupupload](http://www.plupload.com/) to upload files. if I try to load an `exe` with IE9 and the filesize it's over `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` setting, the uploaded file is corrupt.

This is the PHP script that I am using:

```
<?php
/**
 * upload.php
 *
 * Copyright 2013, Moxiecode Systems AB
 * Released under GPL License.
 *
 * License: http://www.plupload.com/license
 * Contributing: http://www.plupload.com/contributing
 */

// Make sure file is not cached (as it happens for example on iOS devices)
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(5 * 60);

// Settings
$targetDir  = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "upload";

// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
    @mkdir($targetDir);
}

// Get a file name
if (isset($_REQUEST["name"])) {
    $fileName = $_REQUEST["name"];
} elseif (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
} else {
    $fileName = uniqid("file_");
}

$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

// Chunking might be enabled
$chunk  = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"])  ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"])  : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;


// Open temp file
if (!$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunks ? "ab" : "wb")) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
    if (!$in = @fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "rb")) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
} else {    
    if (!$in = @fopen("php://input", "rb")) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
}

while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
    fwrite($out, $buff);
}

@fclose($out);
@fclose($in);

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}

// Return Success JSON-RPC response
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');
```

upload occurs through the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

<title>Plupload - Custom example</title>

<!-- production -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="font: 13px Verdana; background: #eee; color: #333">

<h1>Custom example</h1>

<p>Shows you how to use the core plupload API.</p>

<div id="filelist">Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</div>
<br />

<div id="container">
    <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[Select files]</a> 
    <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[Upload files]</a>
</div>

<br />
<pre id="console"></pre>


<script type="text/javascript">
// Custom example logic

var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
    container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
    url : 'upload.php',
    flash_swf_url : '../js/Moxie.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : '../js/Moxie.xap',
    chunk_size : '2mb',

    filters : {
        max_file_size : '100mb',
        mime_types: [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
            {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"},
            {title : "Exe files", extensions : "exe"}
        ]
    },

    init: {
        PostInit: function() {
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';

            document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
                uploader.start();
                return false;
            };
        },

        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>';
            });
        },

        UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
            document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
        },

        Error: function(up, err) {
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
        }
    }
});

uploader.init();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the `exe` are corrupt, if I try to open them with `notepad++`, I find:

[image]

My setting:

```
PHP Version 5.5.9
System          Windows NT PC-XXX 6.0 build 6002 (Windows Vista Service Pack 2) i586 
Compiler        MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012) 
Architecture    x86 
Server API      Apache 2.0 Handler
```

php.ini

```
max_execution_time=30
max_input_time=60
memory_limit=128M
max_file_uploads=20
```

Additional info

1. All Plupupload methods (html5,flash,silverlight,html4) have the problem
2. Antivirus disabled
3. UAC is disabled

**TRY ISSUE YOURSELF**

I have created a package for anyone who wants to try.

Download package: http://www.sndesign.it/shared/stackoverflow/plupload-2.1.2.zip

My `plupload-2.1.2.zip` also contains a corrupted upload file in `plupload-2.1.2/examples/upload/file_54c4c1d05c2ef` folder and the file to try to upload `plupload-2.1.2/examples/TryMe.exe`

Prepare for the test (I use [XAMPP Version 1.8.3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.3/)):

1. Unzip `plupload-2.1.2.zip` in your `htdocs`
2. set `php.ini` `upload_max_filesize=22M` `post_max_size=22M` (less to TryMe.exe file size 23MB), restart Apache
3. Open IE9 (IE9 always fails), and go to: `http://localhost/plupload-2.1.2/examples/custom.html`
4. Select file in `%YourHtdocs%/plupload-2.1.2/examples/TryMe.exe` and upload
5. go in `%YourHtdocs%/plupload-2.1.2/examples/upload/` and find the uploaded file
6. the uploaded file is corrupted.
7. set `php.ini` `upload_max_filesize=24M` `post_max_size=24M` (up to TryMe.exe file size 23MB), restart Apache
8. Select file in `%YourHtdocs%/plupload-2.1.2/examples/TryMe.exe` and upload
9. go in `%YourHtdocs%/plupload-2.1.2/examples/upload/` and find the uploaded file
10. the uploaded file is ok.

Comment: @maytham is for a service that collects indie software, uploaded by developers.

Comment: @maytham What kind of problems did you have ? I tried it with images and zip and works well

Comment: @maytham I reported the problem even on [github plupupload project](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/1193) . Stay tuned, maybe someone finds a solution...

Comment: @maytham I started a bounty. if you are interested in this issue you can add bounty or vote up this question to give it more visibility.

Comment: Since you said you can strip the headers out using notepad++, have you tried stripping them out programatically?

Comment: @TecBrat Yep. But I would like to solve the problem and not find a patch

Comment: locate your problem by using one upload method each time (html5, flash etc.)

Comment: @Deadooshka all methods have the problem.

Comment: also try to upload renamed exe file with another extension

Comment: @Deadooshka I tried to rename `exe` before upload to `zip` or `jpg`, but still does not work . thanks for your help

Comment: @SimoneNigro just an idea, is it posible to find out if php are able to zip files fly and upload them? if that helps?

Comment: should javascript zip on the fly :(

Comment: @maytham I'm sorry but my English is very bad . What do you mean: ppl

Comment: to work the exe file must be zipped before uploading. So, should the client to zip the fly, so javascript

Comment: Hmmm true; I agree javascript way, i am not a ware of if there is a javascript to do this, if you find let me know?

Comment: try to add ".exe" to "low risk files" like described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/06/19/how-to-bypass-the-security-warning-unknown-publisher-with-the-checkbox-always-ask-before-opening-this-file.aspx)

Comment: I think it must be some Group Policy setting. Turn off UAC in Vista.

Comment: UAC is already disabled

Comment: CHANGE EXTENSION FROM EXE TO ABC AND THEN UPLOAD

Comment: @Innovation not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we know is that an intact file is split up into chunks, each of which is prefixed by an HTTP `multipart/form-data` header and a `Content-Disposition` header. The first one is always stripped correctly, the second one is not.
This leaves us with 3 possibilities:

1. At least one of the headers is corrupted when the file is sent.
2. At least one of the headers is corrupted after it was sent by the browser but before it is parsed by PHP.
3. Something goes wrong while PHP is parsing the request.

The cause for any of the above could be destructive filtering by a firewall, antivirus or any other service that for some reason feels the need to go over your network traffic or RAM/file system activity. For **1.** it could also be a bug in the browser/JavaScript/Flash/Silverlight/PlUpload engine. For **2.** it could theoretically be Apache messing something up, but that is extremely unlikely since it passes the data 1:1 on to PHP. Now for **3.** we can't rule out a bug in PHP, but that is too extremely unlikely since PHP is a constant here and the results vary with different browsers. But I can imagine PHP receives the file, saves it together with the second header, then the file locked because some service is filtering it, filtering takes long because the file is untrusted and big, PHP tries to remove the second header but is denied access because the filtering is still going on and at the end you are left with a file with header. The different outcomes with different browsers could be explained by different chunk sizes or simply the browser performance.

Unfortunately, that's all just speculation. Now since Microsoft did their very best to make it as hard as possible to downgrade IE, I'm currently unable to test it with IE9, all I can give you is some debugging instructions:

In your php.ini, set

```
enable_post_data_reading = Off
```

this will completely break all POST requests on that server, but it will allow you to read and dump the file upload requests.

In your upload.php, add those two lines before any other code:

```
file_put_contents('out.txt', print_r(getallheaders(), true).PHP_EOL.substr(file_get_contents('php://input'), 0, 1000), FILE_APPEND);
exit;
```

Start Apache and upload TryMe.exe with IE9. Next to your upload.php should now be an out.txt file containing all the relevant data about the file upload requests. Please upload that file somewhere and give us a link to it.

Comment: thanks for your help, you can download the output file http://www.sndesign.it/shared/stackoverflow/out.txt

Comment: Well, **[this](http://pastebin.com/KerXq6Wh)** is the result with IE11, notice how the `chunk` and `chunks` sections are missing? Could you give me a dump when uploading a file that works with IE9?

Comment: How small? Smaller than 2MB? or 8KB?

Comment: fail if filesize is over `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size`

Comment: But it happens with signed exes, unsigned exes and any other file type?

Comment: I think I found the problem: `$in = @fopen("php://input", "rb")`. Why would you do that? If `$_FILES` is empty, the upload has obviously failed. Try returning an error instead, and see what then happens in IE9.

Comment: First in your JavaScript, set `chunk_size` to the same as `upload_max_file_size` or `post_max_size` from the php.ini. If the browser is still not chunking the file, report this as a Plupload bug.

Comment: IE9 not chunking the file...  `chunk_size: '1mb' ` in php error log `PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 23827605 bytes exceeds the limit of 5242880` in php.ini set `upload_max_filesize=5M`
`post_max_size=5M`

Comment: Then report that to the Plupload people.

Answer (score 2):

By default PHP max upload file size is set to 2MB.

Try updating your php settings (php.ini):

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 22M
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize and http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: Note that you need to restart your apache server before the settings take effect (if you haven't)

Comment: Ah, I also noticed in your post that you haven't defined "chunk_size" when you instantiated plupload.

Comment: Have you tried using a different large exe file (something safe from Microsoft maybe)? Would you also know if you have some background process (anti-virus, jobs, etc) that might affect this? I just want to get these out of the way...

Comment: What I meant was to try a large Microsoft exe file, I think it is safe to assume that other file types would work except for exe files larger than 2MB

Comment: Hmm, try another? Maybe larger around 5MB-10MB and up to the size of the file you're having problem with, then try larger. That way you can deduct other possibilities...

Comment: Wondering what's the problem with the original exe file? Could it be running at the time when you were uploading it? Could it be that an anti-virus process is still alive and monitoring that file?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't add up but glad it works for you now. Question now would be what technical/encoding/etc difference between a signed/unsigned exe file? Just wondering, are you signing using sn.exe?

Comment: Ha! I'm not actually inclined to the signed/unsigned issue. I'm thinking there's something happening during the signing process that makes your exe file uploadable.

Comment: It's because signed exe files are "from trusted developpers" it's a security issue

Comment: Indeed if ​​increase the values over the file size to upload, it works. However it should not work that way. I deleted my other comments because they were wrong . Only now I have found exactly the problem.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense at all. If increasing the value solved the problem, upload won't need to be in chunks.